# Do not work ParamConverter with "fos_rest.request_body" converter

Tags: symfony, propel, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to use FOSRestBundle's request body converter but my current implementation doesn't seem to work.

I am using Symfony2, Propel, AngularJS (it sends data to server)

What am i doing wrong?

config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    include_format:       false     
view:
    view_response_listener: force
body_listener: true
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_converter:
    enabled: true

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
    request: { converters: true }
```

Method:

```
/**
 * @View()
 * @Put("/documenttypes")
 * @ParamConverter("documentType", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */
public function putAction(DocumentType $documentType)
{
    print_r($documentType);
    return $documentType;
}
```

In result I have empty model object:

```
Backend\SettingsBundle\Model\DocumentType Object
(
  [id:protected] => 
  [name:protected] => 
  ....
)
```

To check that data comes to server, I modify method:

```
public function putAction(DocumentType $documentType)
  {
    $content = $this->get("request")->getContent();
    $documentType->fromArray(json_decode($content, true));

    print_r($documentType);
    return $documentType;
  }
```

This method works and fills model field:

```
Backend\SettingsBundle\Model\DocumentType Object
(
  [id:protected] => 2
  [name:protected] => 'Oferta'
  ....
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Symfony is complaining that You need to enable `fos_rest.converter.request_body` service.

In your `fos_rest` configuration section within `config.yml` you need to enable `body_converter` feature:

```
fos_rest:
  body_converter:
    enabled: true
```

Now if you list your services, you will notice that service `fos_rest.converter.request_body` has appeared:

```
user@host:~/symfony-project$ php app/console debug:container | grep fos_rest.converter
 fos_rest.converter.request_body       FOS\RestBundle\Request\RequestBodyParamConverter
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I'm not work with Symfony anymore, so I can't confirm you answer. Sorry.

Comment: It returns `No converter named "fos_rest.converter.request_body" found for conversion of parameter XXX.`